# Giving textbox look and feel to <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

I was looking for jQ plug-in which gives same result as StackOverflow tags. Found one using [Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). The problem is, it uses `ul, li` technique and when I use it inside form with another real textboxes, it looks totally different. For example take a look at this picture.

[image]

The first is - Tokeninput. And second is standard textbox. What I want to get is exactly same look and feel of textbox or another jQ plug-in that does same thing as Tokeninput but for textboxes (not `ul li` based).

Here is CSS for horizontal ul that plug-in authors tried to give same look and feel as real textbox.

```
ul.token-input-list {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 1%;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(240,240,240);
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb3CX/1/), i wrote it a few month ago

It enhances a normal textarea and splits the initial textarea value on the "," character to create the tags.

It may not feet your needs 100%, but its a good starting point and can be easily modified.